# getMetadata() not returning metadata from file in Firebase Storage iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, metadata, firebase-storage

I try to get metadata of files from Firebase Storage, in particular date of create (because I want to compare date of local file and date of Cloud file and change file, if needed). I use getMetadata { (metadata, error) in ...} method, but I don't get result in my completion. Control doesn't go to completion! My code is below

```
let metadataURL = Storage.storage().reference().child("tutorials/how_to/use_masking/cover.jpg")

metadataURL.getMetadata { (metadata, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } else {
        if let data = metadata {
            let dict = data.dictionaryRepresentation()

            print(dict)
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to say now, that image is really in this path, because I get this image with getData(...) method in the next step.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: @ConstantinGeorgiu no :(